# How many times do you have to play until you get the humble scrap and unlock the palicos island

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

How many times do you have to play the caravan quests until you get the humble scrap and unlock the palicos island?

Answer (score 1):

Once you get to 4* caravan quests and get to Cheeko Sands, you will get some quests that will eventually unlock all of the Palico facilities, including the island and the minigame to get more humble scrap.

The specific quests are [Wild Palico Panic](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/quest/caravan/4/wild-palico-panic) (which will give you an additional palico) and then [Meownster Hunter Havoc](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/quest/caravan/4/meownster-hunter-havoc) (which unlocks everything else).